# django-postman + django-ajax-selects usage

Tags: python, django, django-ajax-selects

So i have just started using `django-postman==3.2.2` and i am trying to integrate auto-complete using `django-ajax-selects==1.3.6` while using `django-authtools==1.2.0` to have a custom user model with no luck.

**settings.py**

```
AJAX_LOOKUP_CHANNELS = {
    'postman_users': dict(model='authtools.user', search_field='email'),
}
POSTMAN_AUTOCOMPLETER_APP = {
    'arg_default': 'postman_users',
}
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authtools.User'
```

I tried changing from `model='authtools.user` to `model='auth.user` but it doesn't work.

**urls.py**

```
from ajax_select import urls as ajax_select_urls

url(r'^messages/lookups/',
        include(ajax_select_urls)),
url(r'^messages/', include('postman.urls')),
```

I then go to the built in postman view http://localhost:8000/messages/write/ and when i fill the recipients input nothing happens.

What am i missing? Isn't this supposed to work with just these settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround i ended up using `django-autocomplete-light` which i found much easier to use and understand than `django-ajax-selects`
I then created my own extended form and passed to the write view:

```
class MyCustomWriteForm(BaseWriteForm):
    recipients = autocomplete_light.ChoiceField(
        'UserAutocomplete', label='recipients')

    class Meta(BaseWriteForm.Meta):
        fields = ('recipients', 'subject', 'body')
```

in my urls.py:

```
url(r'^messages/write/(?:(?P<recipients>[^/#]+)/)?$', WriteView.as_view(form_classes=(MyCustomWriteForm, AnonymousWriteForm)), name='write'),
```

I think this was about it.